# Identify $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $ [- \frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have read somewhere that we can identify the group $\mathbb{Z}_n= \lbrace 0,...,n-1\rbrace $ with the interval $[- \frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2})$ but there was no justification for this, does anyone have an argument which prove that this is true?

Comment: I don't understand. What does it mean to identify a group with an interval? Does it mean that $\mathbb Z_n\mapsto \left[-\frac n2, \frac n2\right)$ is a one to one correspondence between two collection of sets?

Comment: Would it not rather be this notation defined as follows? $[\![ 0,4[\![:=\{0,1,2,3\} $

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen, this is exactly what I think they mean by identifying the two sets, actually they didn't not explicitly explained it  but I think it might be this!

Comment: @Asma Now it does make sense. Indeed, for example, $\mathbb Z_5\mapsto\{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}$. Such an identification works.

Answer (score 0):

We can identify two sets provided we have a bijection between them. And we can identify two *structured sets* (read group, ring, field, vector space, etc.) provided we have an isomorphism between them.

But here we have more. The identification you cite is rather canonic. It is because through the canonical projection

$$\begin{aligned}
P_n:\space&\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \\
&p\mapsto\mod(p,n)
\end{aligned}
$$

we know that $P_n(p) = P_n(q) \iff p\equiv q \mod(n)$

In particular, we have $P_n(n-1) = P_n(-1),\dots,P_n\left(\frac n 2\right)=P_n\left(\frac {-n} 2\right)$, which gives the identification

(I have followed here your convention to note $\frac p q$ the quotient of the euclidian division)

Comment: $P_n(n-1) = P_n(-1)$ so $P_n$ is not injective.